# Php Array Problem

Tags: php, arrays

i got this array.

```
array(24) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["category"]=> string(5) "Alles"
        ["description"]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "11"
        ["category"]=> string(6) "Cinema"
        ["description"]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [2]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "8"
        ["category"]=> string(8) "Computer"
        ["description"]=> string(0) ""
    }
}
```

And i dont know how to show this informations:

I tried with:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($array); ++$x)
{

     echo "key: ".key($array)."<br>value: ".current($array)."<br>";
     next($array);

}
```

The Key value is now right, but the current-value is also an array :(
I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) 
{
```

> echo  "key: " . ' '.$key .', '.
>
> "category: " . ' ' . $value['category'].',
>
> "description: " . ' ' . $value['description'];

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested foreach loops i.e.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    echo "[ ".$key." ]<br/>";
    foreach ($value as $innerKey => $innerValue){
         echo $innerKey." => ".$innerValue."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over this array as follows:

```
foreach($sourceArray as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Item: ' . $value . '<br />';
    foreach($value as $subKey => $subValue) {
        echo $subKey.' -> '.$subValue.'<br />';
    }
}
```